# Paragraph Symbol Causing Web Page To Crash

Tags: python

I'm writing a website/search engine with a Python back end, and every time a paragraph symbol shows up in my search results, the page gets a 500 server error. Does anyone know how I might be able to reformat the string containing the results so that it will get rid of the paragraph symbol?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a encode/decode error. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Can you paste the traceback nor the code ?

Comment: This is happening in deployment, so I have no traceback unfortunately. But I think you're right that it's an encode/decode error. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The traceback should be in the server log on the productive system.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with text encoding. Make sure you're using [Unicode strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) as much as possible, and if it's not possible, always specify the encoding.